# Python Split Lines and write it in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was trying to code a python program so that I can read a `txt` file that has jumbled up things like date, time, name and status in each line and I want to split all file's line and do something like shown below. I have also searched in Internet and I did not find it.

My `txt` file is:

```
12/30/20
4:48 PM
PY New
Refund
12/30/20
4:24 PM
Not Refund
Done
```

And I want that program to write something like this:

```
  Date           Time           Name         Status
12/30/20        4:48 PM        PY New        Refund
12/30/20        4:24 PM        Not Refund    Done
```

Here is my python code:

```
filename = "RawData.txt"
with open(filename, "r") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        while 3 > 0:
            print(line.strip(""))
            break

with open("ProcessedData.txt", "w") as fin:
    #"newdata" is the variable that will store the data after splitting in 3 lines.
    fin.write(newdata)
```

Comment: Why are you opening the second file with, `wb` (write bytes), shouldn't it be `w`?

Comment: Yes, it should be `w` @Abhigyan

Comment: So it fixed the problem?

Comment: No, it didn't fix the problem @AbhigyanJaiswal

Comment: I got an error that says:`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Misc\Data Entry\HlpedP\All Data\Formatting.py", line 6, in <module> fin2.write(''.join(line.ljust(15) for line in lines[i:i+4]) + "\n") File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9d' in position 28: character maps to <undefined> ` @AnnZen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use the third parameter of the `range()` method, the `step`:

```
filename = "RawData.txt"
with open(filename, "r") as fin, open("ProcessedData.txt", "w") as fin2:
    fin2.write("  Date           Time           Name         Status" + "\n")
    lines = fin.read().splitlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 4):
        fin2.write(''.join(line.ljust(15) for line in lines[i:i+4]) + "\n")
```

`ProcessedData.txt` result:

```
  Date           Time           Name         Status
12/30/20       4:48 PM        PY New         Refund         
12/30/20       4:24 PM        Not Refund     Done
```

Now, if you look at the resulting data inside `ProcessedData.txt` as a `txt` file, it might not look so neat. The reason would be because of the font.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):  
  
File "C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Misc\Data Entry\HlpedP\All Data\Formatting.py", line 6, in <module>  
fin2.write(''.join(line.ljust(15) for line in lines[i:i+4]) + "\n")  

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]  

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x9d' in position 28:
character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @Mr.LegalBoy Try adding `encoding="utf-8"` to the `open` function as the last argument.

Comment: Yes, I added `encoding="utf-8"` and now it is working, thank you very much indeed. @AnnZen